# Caffe and crontab

Tags: python-2.7, cron, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I'm trying to run a python script through crontab like this

```
@reboot cd /root/open_nsfw/ && /usr/bin/screen -dm -L /usr/bin/python /root/open_nsfw/fn_tcp2.py
```

but fails cause can't find *caffe* `ImportError: No module named caffe`

`caffe.__file__` gives me this output

```
/root/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.pyc
```

the output of `sys.path` run by crontab is

```
['/root/open_nsfw', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat']
```

(no caffe)
but from shell is

```
['', '/root/caffe/python', '/root/open_nsfw', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat']
```

(caffe is there!)
so, I think I have all the elements to fix this but I can't figure out how!

please advise, thanks!

---

EDIT
solved adding these lines at the beginning of the script

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/root/caffe/python/")
```

Answer (score 0):

when running from `crontab` you do not have environment variables set as in shell. You only get the very minimum. You need to explicitly set `PYTHONPATH` to include caffe in your crontab script

Comment: tried to edit crontab with this `@reboot PYTHONPATH=/root/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH && cd /root/open_nsfw/ && /usr/bin/screen -dm -L /usr/bin/python /root/open_nsfw/fn_tcp2.py` but still it can't find caffe

Comment: try set the pah in screen